# Name for rings with $R \cong R^{\mathrm{op}}$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, terminology

Is there a name for rings that are isomorphic to their opposite ring $R^{\mathrm{op}}$ in the literature? I'm especially interested for the class of Artin algebras.

Comment: +1 In my experience, I haven't seen such a term. There might not be because the phrase "isomorphic to its opposite ring" is already very clear and doesn't benefit much from more compression.  A good word would be something like "symmetric" or "balanced" but alas I think these already have other uses...

Comment: @rschwieb I think it would be good to have a short word for such rings, as always writing "isomorphic to its opposite ring" is a little long. How about "opp-isomorphic" in case no word exists at the moment? Any other (probably better) suggestions are welcome. Symmetric is already in use and Im not sure about balanced (there are balanced modules at least and also rings as I just learned: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_module ).

Comment: The terms "symmetric ring" and "reversible ring" already exist, and  have a different meaning. See G. Marks, *Reversible and symmetric rings*, JPAA **174** (2002).

Comment: An extremely tangential remark is that a more natural property to study seems to be that there is $f \colon R \to R^{op}$ such that $f$ and $f^{op}$ are inverses.

Comment: "Opposable" could be a good name, if you're taking suggestions.

Comment: Dan Petersen's notion is usually called a *ring with duality* and they are important in hermitian K-theory.

Comment: Adapting Bourbaki's terminology (A.III.1.1), one might call such a thing _antiautomorphic._ (The correct form is probably _antiautomorphic to itself_ and is unfortunately rather clumsy...).

Comment: I've sometimes called a semigroup that is isomorphic to its opposite left-right dual.  But I like opposable better.